# ORA-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection ORACLE XE 11.2 x64

Tags: oracle, listener

I'm starting to become very very frustrated by Oracle.
So, I have Oracle XE 11.2 64 bit and ODAC121012_x64 installed.

I can start listener; I can do tnsping xe; but when I try to connect as via sqlplus as system I'm getting:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12518: TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
```

Here are my config files:

tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
     (SID_DESC =
                           (SID_NAME = XE)
       (ORACLE_HOME =  C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
     )

    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

sqlnet.ora:

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

Help is very much needed and will be even more appreciated!

Comment: Can you connect as sysdba?

> connect / as sysdba

Comment: Can you include the output of "lsnrctl status"?

Comment: is your database open? what is the value of the processes parameter?

Comment: >sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jun 27 15:21:58 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: this is to lsnctl status:
http://pastebin.com/QDe4m33V

Comment: @ik_zelf, please, can you be so kind and specify what action do you mean by that? thank you

Comment: Reboot, then restart everything. What OS are you running on (I realise Windows, but what version?)?

Comment: I have rebooted, restarted listeners, services... still the same.
Its win 7 x64 pro.

Comment: @greengold read the alertlog file and see if the database is opened at the end. In the alertlog you also find a dump of the actual parameters with their values. I am not sure where the alertlog will be but start searching in C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\alertxe.log

Answer (score 2):

I has this problem in Windows (with oracle 11g) because the user under which the listener service was running was not part of the administrators group... once added to the administrator group all was fine.

Comment: This is legit one of the answers. if the database and listener service are running as a user which is not part of the administrators group, setting up a static connection doesn't work properly

Comment: +1 this solved an additional problem with Oracle 18c in Windows for me: Oracle services had to be started manually, they didn't start automatically. I added all NT_SERVICE/Oracle* service users to Administrators group.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I believe this could be the cause of my 12518 after trying everything. However, when the users were created, I can see that they appear correctly in the task administrator as the owner of the Oracle process, but they don't appear in the account management menu in the control panel. Is there something I should worry? Their folders are created correctly under the User folder

Comment: This is hell of an answer. Needs more recognition. For this change the user of listener service from properties.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the problem and try to fix it you need to check related logs: 
 listener.log, alert log, trace file, etc

possible causes and solutions:

- listener problem:

Make sure there is no error message and listener is up and running by execute the following command:

```
lsnrclt status
```

if listener is down check the following it may help you troubleshoot this issue:

1. could be network error: check the even log for any network error and fix them.
2. service stopped or it has failure when trying to start:  `start--->run--->services.msc` the search for oracle listener service  should be like `OracleInstancename`  try to start it, if it failed to start it will throw an exception inside listener error and windows error number. please provide that error

listener workaround:

add the following parameter to your listener:

```
DIRECT_HANDOFF_TTC_LISTENER=OFF
```

---

- database problem:

1.database server memory were enough for new connection

2. database connection parameters such as: dedicated server, please checked processes parameter or query from `v$resource_limit where resource_name=’processes’`; checked max_utilization must less than `Limit_value` or shared server, verify `large_pool_size` or check dispatcher were enough for all connection.

Comment: +1 for new connection memory limit. In my case a leaking app was making my oracle to reject any new connection attempt, with this message.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12518 or TNS-12518 can occur, if you have a Linux system with systemd 228 or newer. Systemd by default limits the number of threads to 512 per cgroup. This limit can easily been hit, if you have many connections or more than one instance or RAC or ....

Easiest fix: Edit /etc/systemd/system.conf and set

```
DefaultTasksMax=infinity
```